# Proving sequence result using integrals

Tags: sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I need to prove that

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{n}{n^2 + k^2} =  \frac{\pi}{4}$$

using definite integrals.
I would like to get a explanation about to do it , and whats the reasons.
thanks!!

Comment: and what did you try?

Comment: @alexjo Well i thought about trying to convert it to a function and try to calculate the integral. but just got the feeling I'm not in the right way.

Comment: You have to recognize this as a Riemann sum for an appropriate function.  The limit is then the actual integral.

Comment: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{1+(k/n)^2} = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{1+x^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{n}{n^{2}+k^{2}}=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\arctan 1=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{4}}.$$